# How to update superview UILabel text from subview in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uilabel

I have two class, **Client_Main** and **Client_demo**.
In **Client_Main** class I am using a label which shows *client name* and after click on a button from **Client_Main** class I have added **Client_demo** class as a *subview*. Now when I click on a button on **Client_demo** class I want to change the text of **Client_Main** class label.

So please suggest me how to do this.

Comment: take a look here http://www.roostersoftstudios.com/2011/04/12/simple-delegate-tutorial-for-ios-development/

Comment: You should send an action message via the responder chain to your view controller. Then your view controller in response to your action message should configure your views as appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put an unique tag for the `UILabel` in superview

`[superview subviews];` returns all the view objects in the superview and from that get the one with the unique tag you set and that is it

```
 for (UILabel *label in [yourSubview.superview]) {
        if (label.tag==uniqueID) {
            //Here is your uilabel instance ,do what you want
        }
    }
```

**OR**

**The proper way : Delegation**

just make a delegate method with implementation on the superview to change on label using its instance.
Fire the delegate method from the subview class

[more on delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626898/how-do-i-create-delegates-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 0):

there is two way to update superview from subview 
   1-Via NSNotification 
   in this approch you have to create notification in superview calass  and set observer like          this

```
//you can write this code in viewDidLoad 

  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self  selector:@selector(notificationEventForUpdateData:)   name:@"NotificationForUpdateHomeScreenData" object:nil];

and define this method notificationEventForUpdateData in same superview class in this method    you can update label textfield etc whatever you want 

 -(void) notificationEventForUpdateData: (NSNotification *)notification
 {
     self.label.text=@"newvalue";
 }
```

from subview you have to post this notification from that action(inside method ) you want           to update like button click or cell selection of table view etc 
    like this way

```
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 postNotificationName:@"NotificationForUpdateHomeScreenData"
```

2- way is Proper delegation